# Was the cast of The Office aware of secrets told on Screen?

Tags: the-office

There have been a few secrets in *The Office* that were kept hidden from the audience throughout the series. For example

1. Jim's Note to Pam
2. Michael's Conversation with Pam as he leaves for Colorado

We the audience never knew what was inside the letter or what Michael said.

But did cast know between them? Or were even they left out of these secrets?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The airport scene has been discussed in numerous articles, and [Fischer has given the answer herself](https://www.elitedaily.com/p/what-did-pam-say-to-michael-at-the-airport-the-office-alum-finally-reveals-the-answer-8968185):

> During an Instagram live on Tuesday, May 1, Fischer — who still has an homage to Pam in her Instagram bio — finally revealed what she and Steve Carrell were talking about in that famous scene. As it turns out, Fischer felt just as strongly about Carrell's departure as Pam did about Michael's, because the emotions fans see on screen were totally real:
>
> > That was me talking to Steve. I told him all the ways I was going to miss him when he left our show. Those were real tears and a real goodbye. That was a really emotional scene.
>
> [...]
>
> In her talking head interview after she and Michael have parted ways, Pam is crying, so I have to imagine that these were real tears, as well. **"No, he wasn't sad," she says through tears. "He was full of hope. About Colorado. And he was hoping to get an upgrade as an awards member. And he said that he was just real excited to get home and see Holly."**

Answer (score 5):

### What was in the note? Only Jenna Fischer and John Krasinski know.

In the *Office Ladies* behind the scenes podcast for the episode, 'Christmas Party', Jenna Fischer and Angela Kinsey discuss the note:

> **Jenna Fischer**: I'm gunna say something I've never said before. I also feel like I'm maybe gunna cry.
>
> **Angela Kinsey**: What? Wait. Wait.
>
> **Jenna**: What?
>
> **Angela**: Are you gunna say what was in the note? Are you gunna say what was in the note?
>
> **Jenna**: Sort of.
>
> **Angela**: Because I don't know what was on that card, none of us do
>
> **Jenna**: I'm the only one who knows, and John knows.
>
> **Angela**: Oh my gosh, lady.
>
> **Jenna**: In that episode in season 9, **I believe Greg [Daniels] suggested to John that he write a personal message from himself to me, just saying what our time together on The Office meant to him.**
>
> **Angela**: Aww Jenna.
>
> **Jenna**: Because we were wrapping up filming, we were wrapping up the series and we were all so emotional at that time, you know?
>
> **Angela**: We were all sort of saying good bye in different ways.
>
> **Jenna**: We were. And so, that was his [John's] goodbye.
>
> ...
>
> **Jenna**: It was the sweetest note and you know on camera, Pam says, "I'll never say what it said, but just know it was perfect". **We'll, I'll never say exactly what John wrote, but just know that it was perfect.**